# How to select text with mouse scrolling in vim?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I want to copy some content on remote host in vim, which will last for more than 1 page. But when clicked by `left-click` of mouse, and scrolling down, I find I was stuck at the first page.

I know I can use `scp` or first `cat file` then select.

But is there a way to enable mouse scrolling to do such a selection in vim?

Comment: do you start remote vim via ssh? do you want to "copy" the text from remote machine and "paste" to your local machine? it is not easy to be done with vim.

Comment: @Kent, yes. But on my tmux I can copy a page-view of remote vim content and copy to my local env. The only thing left is the scrolling stuff.

Comment: you should mention that info in question. you started local tmux, and in one window ssh into a remote machine, open a file in remove vim. This question is actually a tmux question, not a vim one. because you are doing tmux selection, not vim.

Comment: you could avoid ssh using netrw (`:h netrw-start`), then you can yank with `+` or `*` registers

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck at the first page"? Does Vim not scroll with the mouse at all? Or it doesn't scroll while {doing something, I'm not clear on exactly what you're doing}?

Comment: @Ben, I can scroll normally with touchpad, but can't scroll down to view more when using `left-click` to select text(hightlight).

Comment: So you cannot scroll *while holding the mouse button down*? I.e. while dragging the mouse to set the selection?

Comment: @Ben, yes. Don't tell me you can do that in your vim?

Comment: I can, but I don't. And I use gvim (on Windows) rather than vim in a terminal. My 'mouse' option may be set differently. I added a possible answer.

Comment: Yes, in gvim you can do that, but vim seems can't accomplish that work.

Comment: this question is not much related to programming, move to superuser.com?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd avoid the problem entirely. Start a selection using <kbd>v</kbd> before you start scrolling. Then the start of the selection stays put and only the end of the selection moves as you scroll. Then make sure to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click instead of just clicking to set the end position.

But if you really want to be able to scroll with the mouse while holding the button to select text, check your 'mouse' option to make sure it contains "a" or "v". It sounds like you may be using a "modeless selection" (:help gui-mouse-modeless) by mistake. A modeless selection only allows you to select text currently on the screen (it does not scroll), but it also lets you select non-text like line numbers.

Also check that you don't have any mappings defined for the scroll events documented in :help scroll-mouse-wheel. For me this feature "just works" in Windows gvim, so I'm not sure what would cause it to not work for you. But I had to try it out so see, since I almost never do that anyway.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "check your 'mouse' option to make sure it contains "a" or "v"" could you elaborate, please?

Comment: You can set options in Vim, such as 'autoindent' or 'hlsearch' or 'number'. One of those options is 'mouse' and it takes a string of letters with various meanings. See the current value by issuing the command, ":set mouse?". That is, press the ':' key, type (without quotes) "set mouse?", and press ENTER. That will show you the current setting. To add characters, you can do something like ":set mouse+=a". Or set it to a specific value with just "=" instead of "+=". To see what values are available, try ":help 'mouse'".

Answer (score -1):

If you are connecting from a system with an X11 server, use `ssh -X` to enable X11 forwarding. This will allow you to connect to the clipboard of your local machine from the remote vim.

For more information on how to use the X11 clipboard check vim's help for [x11-selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#x11-selection).

Comment: iterm2 already allows me to do that. What I desire is `What I yank in remote host vim goes directly to my local clipboard`, since I already configured `set clipboard=unnamed` on remote host

Comment: Using `-X` will allow your __remote__ vim to connect to your __local__ clipboard.